coroutine was never awaited when running my test functions with pytest-asyncio and moto
I have a function that lists and returns dynamodb tables
async def func(connectionId: str | None) -> list[str]:
    async with aioboto3.Session().client("dynamodb") as db:
        response = await db.list_tables()
        table_names = response.get('TableNames', [])

    return table_names

I'm writing a unit test for this function with moto
@pytest.mark.asyncio
@mock_aws
async def test_func():
    async with aioboto3.Session().client("dynamodb") as db:
        exp_result = ['test']
        await db.create_table(
                    TableName='test',
                    KeySchema=[{'AttributeName': 'connectionId', 'KeyType': 'HASH'}],
                    AttributeDefinitions=[{'AttributeName': 'connectionId', 'AttributeType': 'S'}],
                    ProvisionedThroughput={'ReadCapacityUnits': 1, 'WriteCapacityUnits': 1}
                )

        result = await func("2")
        assert result == exp_result

This gives me an error
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'test_func' was never awaited

This seems to be happening only if I layer both moto and pytest-asyncio
If I leave out the async parts and create my function, the tests do pass
Function
def func(connectionId: str | None) -> list[str]:
    db = boto3.client('dynamodb')

    response = db.list_tables()
    table_names = response.get('TableNames', [])

    return table_names

Test
@mock_aws
def test_func():
    exp_result = ['test']
    db = boto3.client("dynamodb")
    db.create_table(
                    TableName='test',
                    KeySchema=[{'AttributeName': 'connectionId', 'KeyType': 'HASH'}],
                    AttributeDefinitions=[{'AttributeName': 'connectionId', 'AttributeType': 'S'}],
                    ProvisionedThroughput={'ReadCapacityUnits': 1, 'WriteCapacityUnits': 1}
                )
    result = func("2")
    assert result == exp_result

I'd be happy with some other solution for my problem too. I don't have to use moto
This question seemed to mention that pytest-asyncio needs to be installed, but I have verified that it is installed.
pip list --format=freeze | grep asyncio
>>>
pytest-asyncio==0.23.6


This is from project github readme:
"Note that test classes subclassing the standard unittest library are not supported. Users are advised to use unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase or an async framework such as asynctest"

I'm not subclassing a unittest library though. But I solved this in a different way using unittest's AsyncMock() object

The mock_aws decorator isn't able to handle async functions. Try using it as a context manager instead:
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_func():
    with mock_aws():
        async with aioboto3.Session().client("dynamodb") as db:
            exp_result = ['test']
            await db.create_table(
                        TableName='test',
                        KeySchema=[{'AttributeName': 'connectionId', 'KeyType': 'HASH'}],
                        AttributeDefinitions=[{'AttributeName': 'connectionId', 'AttributeType': 'S'}],
                        ProvisionedThroughput={'ReadCapacityUnits': 1, 'WriteCapacityUnits': 1}
                    )

            result = await func("2")
            assert result == exp_result

